# Is it feasible to run logistic regression on a Latop with 4GB RAM

Tags: r, dplyr, amazon-redshift, sparkr

I am trying to perform a logistic regression in `R` on my data. 
I have created all the model variables and have them in place
in a table on my Redshift database. 
Lets refer to this database as 'Database A' and the table as
'Table A'

## Problem Statement

Is it feasible to run logistic regression on a laptop with 4 GB RAM

## What I don't want to do

I don't want to wait for my query to execute, 
and wait for it to display all the records. I have around 2 million records.
I am not interested in right-clicking and then saving the results as
a CSV file. I think this is really time consuming.

## My research and the dplyr package.

I have gone through [this](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx1G8828SPGX3PK/Connecting-R-with-Amazon-Redshift) blog about connecting R to amazon Redshift
It talks about establishing a connection through the `RJDBC` package.
I am connecting to Redshift from my personal laptop. I am providing the
R version on my laptop for your reference. The `version` command on my laptop outputs the following.

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.5                         
year           2016                        
month          04                          
day            14                          
svn rev        70478                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
nickname       Very, Very Secure Dishes
```

I was able to create a connection to redshift. I used the `tbl` function to  create an R object which points to my 'Table A' in the Amazon Redshift.
The sudo code is below

```
myRedshift <- src_postgres('Database A',
host = 'Host_name',
port = Portnumber,
user = "XXXX", 
password = "XXXX")

my.data <- tbl(myRedshift, "Table A")
```

This works fine. I checked the dimensions. They were correct.

## What I did next was

I tried to use the `tbl_df` function  to store the values of the
`my.data` object in a data frame in R to perform logistic regression.
But the operation just kept running for more than 50 minutes. I aborted R

I also tried to chain the results into a dataframe as

```
new.data <- my.data %>% select(*)
```

But this gave me errors. I have more than 15 columns and I don't want
to type out each column's name.

I searched online and came across `SparkR` It seemed like it could help me
I was following the instructions mentioned in [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-and-starting-sparkr-locally-on-windows-os-and-rstudio/) link. But when
I run the `.\bin\sparkR` command on my windows `cmd` terminal. I get an
error saying

```
Access is denied
The system cannot find the file 'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp'
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

How should I rectify this error ?
What is an efficient method to store the data from my table in Redshift
for me to perform logistic regression ? 
I know of an `unload` function which outputs pipe delimited files,
What should I ask my IT department for using the unload function?

Comment: It seems that you are succesfully loading the data frame, which is at odds with the problem statement of "Look for an efficient way to get the data from Table A in Redshift's Database A inside my 'R' environment".  It seems your problem is more around the amount of time it takes to run a logistic regression.  To answer what appears to be the real question "Is it feasible to do logistic regression with 2 million observations on a laptop with 4GB RAM." the answer will depend on not just the number of observations, but also the number of variables, and the R function being used

Comment: Please could you add (a) the formula that you are using for the regression (b) the results of str(my.data) and (c) the syntax of the R command you are using to run the logistic regression.

Comment: Also, SparkR will help you if you have access to a distributed processing cluster.  Spark is designed to efficiently distribute analytical workload across a cluster.  When running in local mode on a laptop it won't add much efficiency, and could even be slower than base R functions.

Comment: Sure just give me some more time. I will try getting back to you within 6 hours.

Comment: Thanks for the observation. I confused myself with the interpretation of the `tbl` function. I looked online and the `dplyr::collect` has come to my rescue. The model seems to be working. The `mutate` and `transform` functions are also handy to me. I am using `glmnet` for a penalized logistic regression.

Comment: I will update you about my progress by the end of day

Answer (score -1):

So I do have a temporary solution to my problem

As was highlighted, the main issue was the time taken and I was unclear
about how to interpret the `tbl` function.

What helped me use `dplyr` with `Redshift` was the `collect` function.
I could then use `mutate` and `transform` very easily.
Ins stead of using the `baseR` approach of `str` what helps is the
`glimpse` function. It returns whether my.data is a dataframe, the dimensions
and the data types of all variables.

However `collect` takes a lot of time to create the predictors.
I had 6 predictors in my model with more than a million rows. I tried to create my regressors as

```
regressors <- my.data %>%
                filter(required filters) %>%
                select(predictor1, ..., predictor6) %>% collect
```

But this was taking more than an hour. I aborted the operation. I added the 
predictors one by one

```
predictor1 <- my.data %>% filter(required filters) %>%
              select(predictor1) %>% collect
```

I did this for all the 6 predictors each containing more than 1 million records.
The 'numeric`predictors took around 5 minutes to be created.
But predictors which were of type`character` took 10-15 minutes to be created.

For the modeling I am using the `glmnet` function which works fine.

If there is a better way to create my predictor matrix let me know.